# javascript - object literal instanceof Object

Tags: javascript

If I log `[] instanceof Array` it outputs `true`,

but

if I log `{} instanceof Object`, or some other type, I get this error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token instanceof`

Only if I store that object in a **var**, it will not trigger:

```
var a = {}; a instanceof Object
```

So, why do I get that error? how **{}** is different from **[]**?

Comment: `{}` is an empty block of statements. `; instanceof Object` is a syntax error then.

Comment: o my gosh... :|

Comment: please move this answer to the the comments section, I am so dumb, it's the right and obvious answer...

Comment: ({}) instanceof Object  should work

Answer (score 2):

`{ }` is interpreted as a Block statement rather than an object. That is the reason why you get an error.

```js
({}) instanceof Object
```

The above one is the way to check what you wanted.